# Auto Clear & Refill Texta Area Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autofill

I have a simple form using the Value to inform the user what they're to put in each text area. I have been able to make the text area's auto clear using this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(field)
{
    if(''!=field.defaultValue)
    {
        if(field.value==field.defaultValue)
        {
            field.value='';
        }
        else if(''==field.value)
        {
            field.value=field.defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

What would I need to add to have the Value re-appear if the user doesn't fill the text area and they no longer have it selected? Here's the form markup, if that helps any:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
<input type="text" name="first" value="First Name" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)">
<input type="text" name="last" value="Last Name" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)"> <br>
<input type="text" name="address" value="Address" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)">
<input type="text" name="city" value="City" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)"><br>
<input type="text" name="state" value="State" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)">
<input type="text" name="zip" value="Zip" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)"><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)">
<input type="radio" name="day" value="Day"> Day  
<input type="radio" name="evening" value="Evening"> Evening <br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" class="slide-form-input" onfocus="setValue(this)" onblur="setValue(this)">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" class="push_button blue">
```

(sorry for the poor wording, it's early!)

Thank you!
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `placeholder` html5 attribute

```
<input type="text" palceholder="First Name" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MesvN/

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Oh! That's so much easier, completely forgot about html5's placeholder attribute. Thank you!!